# No se actualiza la vista del chat al procesar mensajes con socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, nodejs

estoy tratando de construir un chat con salas, este chat estoy haciéndolo con Jquery para manipular el html y Node.js para el servidor, lo estoy haciendo para aprender programacion basica web y estoy teniendo un problema para añadir los mensajes en el cliente, los mensaje llegan al servidor pero no se añaden la caja de chat del cliente, esto se deveria hacer mediante el client.js que es el encargado de manipular el DOM del html, los mensaje de añaden a una lista sin orden atrabes de los li que agrega el client.js y que le son enviados por el servido, esto lo fui haciendo con ChatGTP3 y para que me explique como funciona, pero ahora llego a un punto muerto donde no consigue explicarme donde se encuentra el problema. Motivo por el que recurro al gente con años de experiencia en esta plataforma, paso a dejar los codigos aqui:

```
//servidor.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//atiende las peticiones de los clientes
app.get('/room/:roomName', (req, res) => {
  const roomName = req.parms.roomName;
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'public','index.html'));
});

// Almacenamiento de los usuarios conectados en un objeto
const connectedUsers = {};
const rooms = new Set(); // Almacena la lista de salas

/*se encarga de maneja las conecciones
      y desconeciones de los usuarios
    */

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('\u001B[34m[SERVER]:a user connected\u001B[34m');
//permite la seleccion de salas de chat
  socket.on('joinRoom', (roomName) => {
    socket.join(roomName);
    console.log(`[SERVER]: ${socket.id} joined room ${roomName}`);
// Obtén la lista de salas de chat del servidor (por ejemplo, desde una base de datos)
    const roomList = ['Room 1', 'Room 2', 'Room 3'];
// Emite la lista de salas de chat al cliente
    socket.emit('roomList', roomList);
  });

//maneja la lista de rooms
  socket.on('getRoomList', () => {
    socket.emit('roomList', Array.from(rooms));
  });

// Recibe el nombre de usuario del cliente y lo agrega al objeto de usuarios conectados

  socket.on('username',(username) => {
    connectedUsers[socket.id] = username;
    console.log('\u001B[34m[SERVER]: ' + username + ' connected\u001B[34m');
  });

  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    const username = connectedUsers[socket.id];
    console.log('\u001B[31m[CLIENT]: ' + username+ ' message: ' + data.message + '\u001B[31m');
//io.emit('message',`${data.username} : ${data.mesa}`);
    io.to(data.roomName).emit('message', `${username}: ${data.message}`);
  });

//determina que alguien se desconecto del servidor
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const username = connectedUsers[socket.id];
    delete connectedUsers[socket.id];
    console.log('\u001B[34m[SERVER]: user ' + username + ' disconnected\u001B[34m');
  });

// Escucha el evento "chat message" emitido por el cliente
  socket.on('chat message', (data) => {
    const username = connectedUsers[socket.id];
    const message = data.message;
    console.log("\u001B[31m[CLIENT]: " + username + " ::> " + data.message + '\u001B[31m');
// Emite el mensaje solo a los clientes en la misma sala de chat
    io.to(data.roomName).emit('message', `${username}: ${message}`);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('\u001B[34m[SERVER]: ***listening on PORT:3000***\u001B[34m');
});
```

```js
// client.js
$(function() {
  // Se crea el socket
  const socket = io();

  // Agregar un controlador de eventos para el formulario de sala de chat en el cliente
  // y emitir el evento joinRoom al servidor con el nombre de la sala de chat:
  $('#room-form').submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const roomName = $('#room-name').val();
    socket.emit('joinRoom', roomName);
    $('.room-form').hide();
    $('.chattype').show();
    // Manipula la lista de rooms
    $('#room-list').empty();
    socket.emit('getRoomList');
  });

  // Agregar un controlador de eventos para el formulario de los usuarios
  $('#username-form').submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = $('#username').val();
    socket.emit('username', username); // Enviamos el nombre del usuario
    $('#username-form').hide(); // Ocultamos el formulario
  });

  // Se usa para mandar el evento al cliente
  $('form').submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const messageInput = $('#m');
    const message = messageInput.val();
    const roomName = $('#room-list').val(); // Obtén el nombre de la sala seleccionada del select
    socket.emit('chat message', {
      username: $('#username').val(),
      message: $('#m').val(),
      roomName: $('#room-list').val(), // Agrega el nombre de la sala de chat al objeto de mensaje
    });
    messageInput.val('');
    return false;
  });

  // Escucha las respuestas del servidor para modificar el HTML y añadir los mensajes
  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    const pos = msg.indexOf(":");
    const sender = msg.substring(0, pos);
    const message = msg.substring(pos + 1);
    const username = $('#username').val();
    const isUserMessage = (username === sender);
    const isUndefinedUser = (typeof username === 'undefined');
    const msgClass = isUserMessage ? 'user-message' : (isUndefinedUser ? 'undef-message' : 'received-message');
    const bgColor = isUserMessage ? '#ffffff' : (msgClass === 'received-message' ? '#f41553a6' : '#9fffffff');

    const li = $('<li>')
      .addClass(msgClass)
      .text(`${sender}: ${message}`)
      .css('background-color', bgColor);

    li.appendTo('#messages');
    $('.chattype').scrollTop($('.chattype')[0].scrollHeight);

  });

  socket.on('roomList', (rooms) => {
    const roomList = $('#room-list');
    roomList.empty(); // Limpia las opciones existentes en el select

    // Agrega las opciones de sala de chat al select
    rooms.forEach((room) => {
      const option = $('<option>').text(room);
      roomList.append(option);
    });
  });
});

// Posiciona el chat siempre al final del scroll
const scrollableDiv = document.getElementById("messages");
scrollableDiv.scrollTop = scrollableDiv.scrollHeight - scrollableDiv.clientHeight
```

```css
/* Este sería el CSS corregido: */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* Estilos para los mensajes */

#messages li {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}


/* Estilos para los textos superiores */

.textsup {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Estilos para los elementos dentro de textsup */

.textsup h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

.textsup h4 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: 0;
}

.username {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  z-index: 2;
}

.room-form {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 3;
}


/* Estilos para la caja de chat */

.chattype {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 90%;
  height: calc(100% - 215px);
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  /* Agregamos margen superior para separarlo del elemento username */
  z-index: 4;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Ajustar tamaño y posición de la caja de chat para pantallas pequeñas */
  .chattype {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 150px);
    top: 20%;
    bottom: 20%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  /* Ajustar tamaño y posición de la caja de chat para pantallas muy pequeñas */
  .chattype {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    top: 30%;
    bottom: 30%;
    font-size: 120%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  /* Ajustar tamaño y posición de la caja de chat para pantallas muy pequeñas */
  .chattype {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
    top: 30%;
    bottom: 30%;
  }
}


/*En este ejemplo, se utiliza la propiedad @media de CSS para definir reglas diferentes para la caja de chat en función del ancho de la pantalla. En pantallas pequeñas, se ajusta el tamaño y la posición de la caja para que no se superponga con el formulario de usuario.
*/

.chattype input {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.chattype button {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Estilos para los mensajes enviados por el usuario */

.user-message {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}


/* Estilos para los mensajes recibidos por el usuario */

.received-message {
  background-color: #f41553a6;
  color: #000000;
}


/* Estilos para el footer */

.foootertype {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffd5b6ad;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .foootertype {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

h10 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

body {
  background-color: #FFFDD0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.text {
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Free Lenguage Chat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stl.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="textsup">
    <h1>Free Lenguage Chat</h1>
    <h4>
      This is a international web platform, created to provide a comunication channel for people that are lerning a lenguage and need practice
    </h4>
  </div>
  <!--aqui se puede registrar un usuario-->
  <div class="username">
    <form id="username-form">
      <label for="username">Enter your username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" autocomplete="off">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!--En el cliente, agregar un formulario para permitir
    al usuario ingresar el nombre de la sala de chat y
    unirse a ella-->
  <div class="room-form">
    <form id="room-form">
      <label for="room-name">Enter room name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="room-name" autocomplete="off">
      <button type="submit">Join Room</button>
    </form>
    <label for="room-list">Select a room:</label>
    <select id="room-list"></select>
  </div>
  <!--caja de chat generica-->
  <div class="chattype">
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <div class="input-container">
      <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="client.js"></script>
  <footer class="foootertype">
    <h10>
      this page is a alfa prototype that are in constant chage if you have someone problem or proposal to improve or implement changes, tell me in this mail: crisalrojar@gmail.com
    </h10>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo, así captarás más atención a la pregunta. El título actual "ahuyenta" a otros usuarios que querrían ayudarte porque no estás dando un resumen de tu problemática desde allí. Lee [ask].

Comment: El mensaje llega a los clientes?

Comment: no, cuando analice con el navegador los mensajes no llegaban al los clientes.

Comment: No entiendo el negativo. La pregunta está bien formulada (IMHO). El hecho de que haya preguntado antes a chatGPT no la hace una mala pregunta, o al menos no la hace merecedora de un voto negativo. Es verdad que el título está defectuoso, pero debemos considerar que el OP no tiene idea de cuál es el problema (tal vez por haber usado chatGPT). Sugiero que el título sea: ***No se actualiza la vista del chat al procesar mensajes con socket.io***

Comment: ok, gracias por el comentario, lo hare